# ¿Cómo puedo exportar datos de un archivo csv a una tabla html en internet?

Tags: html, python, csv

Tengo una tabla en excel que puedo exportar como un archivo csv que tiene los campos "Nombre 1", "Calificación 1" y "Calificación 2" y necesito llenar una tabla en internet con los datos de calificación (rojo y azul) como se muestra en la imagen, ¿puede alguien orientarme sobre como hacer ésto?, tengo un poco de experiencia con python pero puedo intertar con otro lenguaje o herramienta.

Saludos y gracias por su ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Coloca tu código de pruebas, de esta manera conoceremos tus errores e intenciones y podremos ayudarte mas facilmente. Echale un vistazo a [ask]

Comment: Cuando dices, en internet, te refieres a una pagina web que no es un archivo tuyo local que puedas editar, verdad? Lo digo porque si esta en iternet y necesitas interatuar con esa tabla, tal vez podrias plantearte usar [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) para poder llegar a la pagina web e interactuar con la tabla.

Comment: Ya estuve investigando acerca de selenium como sugiere @j.barrio y por lo que revisé cumple con lo que quiero hacer, respecto a ésta pregunta, sólo necesitaba una dirección en la cual seguir, y creo que selenium lo es, me gustaría calificar el comentario de j.barrio como aceptado pero creo que no se puede porque es un comentario.

Comment: @Gerardo con tu comentario es suficiente para mi :) Gracias!